# Any way to force my app to stay open?

Tags: android

I'm working with a client who would like their app to always be visible on the tablet screen for their in-shop/display model. They would like this app to be locked on the screen so that if a person presses the home button it will go home and the app will stay open. Basically they want the app to be the only thing on this tablet. Are there any solutions from a software perspective that I can implement?

Comment: Add wake locks, override the back button to do nothing, and as you can't override the home button. I guess cover it with something on the desk.

Comment: There's partial kiosk mode, like @Alex suggested.  The more complete answer is full kiosk mode.  That requires you to make a launcher app, remove the top status bar, remove the menu button (both of these require system permissions).  If you want to go a step further you can lock it down with device owner permissions to prevent other apps from being installed.

Answer (score 0):

Set the application to kiosk mode

https://developer.android.com/work/cosu.html
https://sdgsystems.com/blog/implementing-kiosk-mode-android-part-1